# find smallest integer $n$ greater than $1$ which satisfies the given condition .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, radicals

what is the smallest greater than $1$ , for which the root of mean square of the first $n$ positive integers is an integer?

In other words,

$$\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2+\dots +n^2}  $$ is an integer.

my first attempt was $1^2+2^2+3^2+\dots +n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

$n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is a multiple of $6$. product of any two consecutive integers is even.

i.e,$3\mid n(n+1)(2n+1)$ and $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}$ is perfect square is sufficient.
how to I continue?
is there exists another solution?
is there exists infinitely many $n$ that satisfies this condition?

Comment: The conditions you state are for the sum inside the square root to be an integer. You need this to be a square number to yield an integer when you take the square root. I believe the smallest such $n$ is $24$.

Comment: There won't be infinitely many integer solutions. This is due to Siegel's theorem that an elliptic curve has only finitely many integer points.

Comment: This question is answered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26540/4900-a-particularly-square-number

Comment: http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/71079/диофантовы-уравнения-суммы-последовательных-квадратов?страница=1&focusedAnswerId=71097#71097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest answer is $24$. Actually, it's the *only* answer (greater than $1$). This is the [cannonball problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_problem), which was solved one century ago.